# Creating attribute based reports in excel?

Tags: excel, attributes, report, dashboard

I'm new to making reports in Excel. I have a dozen large sheets that track attributes, not measures. They are essentially activity logs, and I want to create reports like "Top 5 Items with status of XYZ". Of course, I could simply go to the sheet and filter for that status. However, there are 40 columns, and I want to report on other "Top 5 items with staus of ABC" as well, so that the user has an idea of what to go look for and what needs immediate attention.

I have been researching dashboard and report options for hours and still haven't gotten out of the starting gate on how to do this. I'm looking at Python, Plotly, and a dozen other solutions but it seems something like this should be so simple. Essentially, I want a single report to say somethng like, in fake SQL:

SELECT * FROM [MyBook.Sheet1] WHERE "TheStatus" = "Needs Input"

...as one formatted report / table, and say have 5-6 more variations of this, and collect them all on one dashboard sheet.

In summary, I want to create a dashboard of table reports, where each table report is looking for attributes (no measures), but can't get out of the starting gate on how to create an attribute based report.

Comment: Why not just use filters?  Also, please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "top 5" based on what though?  How would you be ranking them?  You can run a SQL query on your data pretty much as you show in the question: you'd just need to add some formatting.

Comment: As far as "why not use filters", I explained that in the first paragraph. Several people are using the spreadsheet in excel online, and it means we'd constantly be changing filters on each other since with 40 columns, we ask very different questions.

Either way, I found the solution and it was much much simpler than having to write SQL: just simply use pivot tables collected on a "dashboard" sheet.

Comment: I can replicate the exact SQL example above with just pivots, and do that for the 5-6 questions we need answered at a glance. I'm all set. The "Top 5" could have been just the first 5 it came across, but with pivot tables, I'm fine seeing them all.